# On deploying a react redux app to heroku why do we add static.json at root

Tags: reactjs, heroku, redux

why do we add this in static.json file at root =>

```
{
        "root": "dist/",
        "routes": {
        "/**": "index.html"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`static.json` file is used with [`heroku-buildpack-static`](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-static) during deployment with `heroku` for handling static sites and single page web apps.

A number of options can be configured in `static.json`. Amongst them

**`Root`** allows you to specify a different asset root for the directory of your application. By default it is `public_html/`

**Custom Routes**

You can define custom routes that combine to a single file. This allows you to preserve routing for a single page web application. The following operators are supported:

`*` supports a single path segment in the URL. In the configuration below, `/baz.html` would match but `/bar/baz.html` would not.

`**` supports any length in the URL. In the configuration below, both `/route/foo` would work and `/route/foo/bar/baz`.

```
{
  "routes": {
    "/*.html": "index.html",
    "/route/**": "bar/baz.html"
  }
}
```

When serving a single page app, it's useful to support wildcard URLs that serves the `index.html` file, while also continuing to serve JS and CSS files correctly. Route ordering allows you to do both:

```
{
  "routes": {
    "/**": "index.html"
  }
}
```

With the above configuration, your server will return the `index.html` for all paths and any routing is done on `client side` with `react-router`